# Does this family of special matrices have a name?

Tags: matrices, terminology

These are the bisymmetric matrices that are "pyramid" shaped as follows:

$$f(14) =\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\\1& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 5& 5& 5& 5& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 6& 6& 6& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 7& 6& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 7& 6& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 6& 6& 6& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 5& 5& 5& 5& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 1\\1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$f(15) =\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\\1&2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4&4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 5&5& 5& 5& 5& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 6&6& 6& 6& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7&7& 7& 6& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7&8& 7& 6& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6&7& 7& 7& 6& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6&6& 6& 6& 6& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 5&5& 5& 5& 5& 5& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 4& 4&4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 4& 3& 2& 1\\1& 2& 3& 3& 3&3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 3& 2& 1\\1&2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 1\\1&1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

I failed at using Google to find analyses of these matrices or to find references to them in published literature.

Comment: Try the following site to calculate some products, determinant, characteristic polynomial and etc. of your matrices: http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~linear~matrix.html